# Probability of obtaining certain sum in 2nd throw given first throw (dice)

Tags: probability

I just wanted to verify if my solution to this question is correct: "Rolling 3 dice. First is a 3 or less. What is the probability that the sum after the second is a 5 or less."

**My Solution:** The probability the sum after the second is five or less is the same as the probability the sum is 5 or 4 or 3 or 2, which implies $$\begin{aligned}
     P\{\rm{Sum} \leq 5\} = & P\{\rm{Sum} = 2 \mid \rm{First throw} = 1\} \times P\{\rm{First throw} = 1\} + {}\\
   & P\{\rm{Sum} = 3 \mid \rm{First throw} = 1\} \times P\{\rm{First throw} = 1\} + {}\\
   & P\{\rm{Sum} = 3 \mid \rm{First throw} = 2\} \times P\{\rm{First throw} = 2\} + \ldots
  \end{aligned}$$

Clearly for each sum, there are $n-1$ different cases with each term being $1/36$. So, is the probability $10/36$ (**edit**: Is it $9/36$)?

**Edit**: The answers below make sense, but I am now wondering where the logic was wrong in my solution?

Comment: You are calculating $P\{\rm{Sum} \leq 5\}$ but problem asks for $P\{\rm{Sum} \leq 5 \mid \rm{First throw} \leq 3\}$.

Comment: @ZoranLoncarevic Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple tree-like diagram will help to get the enumeration: draw an edge from 1 to 1,2,3,4, i.e. (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4) and so on for two more outcomes on dice one, there's a total of 4+3+2 = 9 of favorable outcomes out of possible 18. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

There are only nine successes, because $4-1$ doesn't count, as $4>3$.
There are eighteen possible outcomes with first roll $\leq3$.
The question, I guess, asks for the probability the sum$\leq5$ *given that* the first is $3$ or less, so it is 
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(A)}$$